# Make slide toggle bottom and top instead left or right with fixed div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML:

I want to work this div in slideToggle logic. But it has two big problems:

1- I don't know why but my fixed div already open when I open the website. Whereas, it must be close.

2- When I click to header, it close. Ok. But if I try open or close my div twice, its not working.

How can I do it?

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uWnjx/278/)

```js
   $('#form .header').click(function() {
     $('#form').stop().animate({
       bottom: "0px"
     }, 500);
   }, function() {
     var height = $('#form').height() - 60;
     $('#form').stop().animate({
       bottom: -height
     }, 500);
   });
```

```css
     #form {
       position: fixed;
       bottom: 0;
       right: 80px;
       width: 400px;
       height: 720px;
       z-index: 99999;
       background: red;
     }
     .header {
       background: gray;
       width: 399px;
       height: 74px;
       cursor: pointer;
     }
```

```html
<div id="form" style="bottom: 0;
            right: 80px;
            width: 400px;
            height: 720px;">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <?php if( function_exists( 'ninja_forms_display_form' ) ){ ninja_forms_display_form( 17 ); } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try utilizing `top` . Adjusted to `-70px` jsfiddle at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uWnjx/279/ so that `.header` would be slightly visible , able to be clicked

```
$(function () {
    var form = $("#form");
    form.find(".header").on("click", function (e) {
        $("#form").animate({
            top: form.css("top") === "-70px" ? "80%" : "-70px"
        }, 500)
    });
});
```